# MS GraphAPI Support for notifications/subscription on Exchange RoomMailBox in delegated mode

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

In delegated API permission mode, we are able to get events () from RoomMailBox calendar but not subscribe for notifications (webhooks) on events changes.

Each time we tried to create notification channel (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions) we got an error :

```
"error": {
      "code": "ExtensionError",
      "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.]",
      "innerError": {
        "request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "date": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    }
```

Moreover, we have full access on RoomMailBox by using user account we used on delegated mode (user account impersonated).

If we try it by using Application permission mode, it's working, we got a subscription channel. Everything is OK.

Could you tell if there is a way to subscribe RoomMailBox (actually it seems you just support UserMailbox & SharedMailBox) calendar events notifications in delegated API permission mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known limitation of create notification API currently.

Delegated user permissions are not allowed to create a subscription to a shared calendar.

Only application permissions (app-only) are possible.

If you need it to be provided, please [submit a user voice request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

See a previous discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3510).

Comment: Hi @allen-wu, do you consider on Exchange site RoomMailbox as shared calendar for graphapi ? 
Yes I ever submit a user voice request here : https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40133578--graphapi-office-365-rest-api-please-add-support

Do you have any ETA on feature availability ?

Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: Yes. RoomMailbox is considered as shared mailbox. Sorry I don't have any ETA or roadmap. You need to pay attention to the User Voice.